# Align divs with position relative horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs inside a div and I want these 3 divs to align horizontally. I was able to do this by giving absolute position but I want them to have relative position. Why I want it to have relative position is, if I zoom out or zoom in, the div size won't change but the elements inside these divs change. I want the div to zoom out/in as well. That is why I want them to have relative position.

```css
.body_clr {
  background-color: #eceff1;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.test_div {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ff {
  width: 40em;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2aabd2;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.overview {
  width: 20em;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 20%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div className="body_clr">

  <div className="test_div"></div>
  <div className="ff"></div>
  <div className="overview"></div>

</div>
```

Right now my divs are not aligned horizontally.

Comment: parent div in display table and elements to center horizontal display table-cell with verticalalign middle, this could be a solution

Answer (score 0):

I would use **flexbox** for this. Take a look at this example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/cfLfLnLx/.

Also use `class` and not `className` to specify the classes of HTML elements.

A more extensive guide to using `flexbox`: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your css:

1. You can't use display: inline-block with float: left ( you have to use float: left or display: inline-block )
2. If you use float: left you have to put a clear after the 2 floated divs ( always ) .

My solve with table-cell

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
.body_clr { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table; }



.col1 { height: 100%; display: table-cell; padding: 0 10px; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

.ff { width: 100%; height: 40px; display: block; background: #000;}
.test_div { width: 100%; height: 40px; display: block; background: red;}
.overview { width: 100%; height: 40px; display: block; background: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="body_clr">

  <div class=" col1">
    <div class="test_div"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="ff"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="overview"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

With float:

```css
.body_clr { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }

.clear { width: 0; height: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block; visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; clear: both; }

.col1 { width: 33.33%; height: 100%; display: block; float: left; padding: 0 10px; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

.ff { width: 100%; height: 40px; display: block; background: #000;}
.test_div { width: 100%; height: 40px; display: block; background: red;}
.overview { width: 100%; height: 40px; display: block; background: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="body_clr">

  <div class=" col1">
    <div class="test_div"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="ff"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="overview"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```